# Two Type with exactly the same assemblyQualifiedName but not equal

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a very simple event handler which use reflection to load message handle class from Assemblies.

When I receive some message, I try to resolve handle class from loaded assemblies. And find out which class could handle the message.

but when I compare the message Type And the handle Interface Type, it returns false always.

I only have one implement for that message type.

```
    foreach(var @interface in info.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (@interface.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (@interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
                typeof(IAsyncMessageSubscriber<>))
                {
                    var arg = @interface.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                    arg.Assembly
                    if (arg == messageType)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

[image: debug details]

Comment: Try printing out their `UnderlyingSystemType`?

Comment: I guess you are comparing references, so the `==` operator will return true of both sides refer to the same _instance_ of what you are comparing. And that seems unlikely.

Comment: @Sweeper I've already tried, that still not woring.

Comment: @oerkelens the operater == of Type have been override by default. it compares the UnderlyingSystemType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is I used Assembly.LoadFrom Not Assembly.Load.
Assembly.LoadFrom load assembly and types into another appdomain that make the type are not equal from current appdomain.
Use Assembly.Load could solve this problem.